# SVN: how to see last revisions updates (show-log) without updating?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

To update a project to the last review within TortoiseSVN i do: "SVN Update".
Is there a way to see the note about new revisions without having to really update my local project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Show log...* shows the latest commits. Not just the latest commits before your last update. It does what you want by default.

Answer (score 3):

**TortoiseSVN:**

**right click** on workingcopy folder/file->"**check for modifications**"->"**Check Repository**"

You will see for all files changed on each side(working copy or repository the current revision number and svn-status)

With double click on each entry you can even preview the result of an svn update

**Commandline Client:**

Use

```
svn log <SERVERURL>
```

gives you the version history on your server

```
svn log <PATH_TO_WORKINGCOPY>
```

gives you the log messages up to last version you checked out or committed

Answer (score 2):

you can use `show log` in form context menu and then you can `compare with working copy` using right context menu of log window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Revision Graph in Tortoise SVN.
See this url for detail.
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-revgraph.html

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on perticular folder/file from your working copy,go to Tortoise svn--->SVn Showlog.you can see there.